# Splice function in javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript

The button on click should generate radio buttons, one at a time, but I have an issue with the text node that should stick with the radio buttons. Here's part of the code:

```
var array = [];
items = document.getElementById("items").value.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    array.push(items[i]);
}
type = document.getElementById("type");
container = document.getElementById("container");
if (type.value == "radio") {
    radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        text = document.createTextNode(array[0]);
        container.appendChild(text);
        container.appendChild(radio);
        array.splice(0,1);
    }
}
```

[image: form screenshot]

So this is the result, but I want the first radio button to have a value of '1', the second '2' etc.

Comment: Your heading says slice but in code you have splice. splice mutates original array so it's not a good practice to use it inside loop.

Comment: This seems like a bizarre way to iterate an array. Is there any reason you want an empty array when the loop has finished? Why not instead use `for(const item of array){}`. In the mean time, it's worth reflecting that `array.length` is dynamically changing as the loop progresses.

Comment: I tried to print the first element of the array with the first radio button. That is my question, how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**F**irst you don't need `array`  the `items` array already contains the elements you want from text input

**A**lso no need to slice/splice  any array

**Y**our problem was that you have to create another unique radio element for every element so what you did is appending same radio element many times which result in adding the radio button once

so  you have to put 
`radio = document.createElement("input");
radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");`  inside the for loop    .     .    .  .

```js
function Z() {
  items = document.getElementById('items').value.split(",");
  type = document.getElementById("type");
  container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = "";
  if (type.value == "radio") {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      text = document.createTextNode(items[i]);
      radio = document.createElement("input");
      radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
      container.appendChild(text);
      container.appendChild(radio);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="Z()" id="items"> type:
<select id="type">
  <option value="radio">Radio</option>
  <option value="checkbox">Text</option>
</select>

<div id='container'></div>
```